# how to do this with wordpress API and php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am really a newbie in Wordpress and php. I created a theme for my website as follows:

[image]

I think my question is clear: in wordpress admin page I have four categories: 1,2,3,4. I want last 2 posts in category 1 to be displayed in section (div) 1 (shown above), last 2 posts in category 2 to be displayed in section (div) 2, and so on. 
As I said, I am novice and I faced a tons of functions in Wordpress documentation. 
for example I used the code below inside index.php (of my custom theme) in section 2 which outputs: "Sorry, no posts matched your criteria."

```
   <?php 
                    $args = array( 'post' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'category_name'=>'تازه ها');
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?> 
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    <?php else:  ?>
                    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; 
                ?>
```

Please give a piece of code to do this.

Comment: I changed tag to category in the post and also changed the code, which still fails, though everything seems ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$posts = get_posts ("cat=1&showposts=2");
if ($posts) 
{
    foreach ($posts as $post):
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endforeach;
}
```

Change `cat=1` to the id of each of the four categories.

Comment: How to get id for any category?

Comment: Maybe through this? `$category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');`

Comment: That would work as well, but if you go to the backend of wordpress and edit the post category the link will be something like `http://example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=1&post_type=post`, the `tag_ID=1` is the category id.

Comment: what do you mean by **tag_ID=1 is the category id**?

Comment: The number 1 is the category id to be used in `get_posts`